# I try to add elements in my object with ngModel and add two statics that are not in the form

Tags: angular, typescript

In my form has every column [(ngModel)]="alumno.data" but i need include two more because  are ID created for database

my object in component.ts

```
alumnos = {
    "Persona_idPersona": "",
    "Telefonos_idTelefonos": ""
  };
```

When the server responds to me it gives me to id the these data (Persona_idPersona, Telefonos_idTelefonos)

in console output show the number correct but when i use http.post show  " " that initial condition

```
registro()
  {
    this.http.post(this.URL + "/persona", this.persona).toPromise().then( (data: any ) => {
      console.log(data[0].idPersona);
      this.alumnos.Persona_idPersona = data[0].idPersona ; 
    });

    this.http.post(this.URL + '/telefono', this.telefonos).toPromise().then( (data: any ) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.alumnos.Telefonos_idTelefonos = data[0].idTelefonos;
    });

    // Hacemos post a un alumnos
    console.log(this.alumnos);
    this.http.post(this.URL , this.alumnos).toPromise().then( ( data: any) =>{
      console.log(data);
    });


  }
```

[Image console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C3i6.png)

The problem is that it sends "" and the assigned numbers are not saved.
How I do it so that the data is saved and sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have async problem.
You can resolve it by `forkJoin` or with `Promise.all` or make it synchronous.

1. example with `forkJoin`

   ```
   import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

   registro() {
     forkJoin({
       persona: this.http.post(this.URL + "/persona", this.persona),
       telefonos: this.http.post(this.URL + '/telefono', this.telefonos)
     }).subscribe(response => {
       this.alumnos.Persona_idPersona = response.persona[0].idPersona ; 
       this.alumnos.Telefonos_idTelefonos = response.telefonos[0].idTelefonos;
       // Hacemos post a un alumnos
       console.log(this.alumnos);
       this.http.post(this.URL , this.alumnos).toPromise()
         .then( ( data: any) =>{
           console.log(data);
         });
   })

   }
   ```
2. example with `Promise.all`

   ```
   async registro() {
     const response = await Promise.all([
       this.http.post(this.URL + "/persona", this.persona).toPromise(),
       this.http.post(this.URL + '/telefono', this.telefonos).toPromise()
     ]);

     this.alumnos.Persona_idPersona = response[0][0].idPersona ; 
     this.alumnos.Telefonos_idTelefonos = response[1][0].idTelefonos;

     // Hacemos post a un alumnos
     console.log(this.alumnos);
     this.http.post(this.URL , this.alumnos).toPromise()
       .then( ( data: any) =>{
         console.log(data);
       });
   }
   ```
3. make it synchronous

   ```
   async registro() {
     const persona = await this.http.post(this.URL + "/persona", this.persona).toPromise();
     this.alumnos.Persona_idPersona = persona[0].idPersona ; 

     const telefonos = await this.http.post(this.URL + '/telefono', this.telefonos).toPromise();

     this.alumnos.Telefonos_idTelefonos = telefonos[0].idTelefonos;

     // Hacemos post a un alumnos
     console.log(this.alumnos);
     this.http.post(this.URL , this.alumnos).toPromise()
       .then( ( data: any) =>{
         console.log(data);
       });
   }
   ```